# $\det(A^4+I)=29$ is not solvable by any $A\in M_4(\mathbb Z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I recently encountered the following problem.

> Given any $A \in M_4(\mathbb Z)$, show that $\det(A^4+I)\ne29$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix.

LHS can be written as the product of $1+{\lambda _i}^4$ where $\lambda _i$ denotes the eigenvalues of A. By using AM-GM inequality, I found that A is either invertible in $M_4(\mathbb Z)$ or has a zero determinant. I cannot go further. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "By using AM-GM inequality, I found that A is either invertible or has a zero determinant." Every square matrix is either invertible or has a zero determinant, and AM-GM has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Invertible in $M_4(\mathbb Z)$ , sorry.

Comment: $A$ may not possess any real eigenvalue. Would you please elaborate on your $AM\ge GM$ argument?

Answer (score 6):

Consider the matrix $A$ modulo $29$.
The matrix $A^4+I$ has determinant $29$ so has rank $3$ and nullity
zero considered as a matrix over $\Bbb F_{29}$. It has a unique null-vector
$u$ up to scalar multiplication: $(A^4+I)u\equiv 0\pmod{29}$
and $(A^4+I)v\equiv 0\pmod{29}$ implies $\newcommand{\la}{\lambda}v\equiv\la u\pmod{29}$.
In particular, taking $v=Au$, we find $Au=\la u\pmod{29}$ for some
$\la$. Then $\la^4+1\equiv0\pmod{29}$. But as $8\nmid(29-1)$, this congruence is insoluble.

Comment: Why must $A^4 + I$ have rank exactly $3$?

Comment: With nullity $\ge2$ the determinant would be divisible by $29^2$. @QiaochuYuan

Comment: Hoo, okay, it's taken me way longer than I expected but I think I believe you. What argument do you have in mind? I thought I had an argument involving reducing the characteristic polynomial $\bmod 29$ but I think it doesn't work, and now the only argument I can think of invokes Smith normal form.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hermite normal form works.

Comment: That $\operatorname{nullity}(A^4+I)\ge2$ implies that $29^2\mid\det(A^4+I)$ is really the key to the proof. Nice observation (and nice application of Hermite normal form). +1.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is a one I was taught from my friend.

$\det(A^4+I)=\det(A^2+I+\sqrt{2}A)\det(A^2+I-\sqrt{2}A)$.
We can put $\det(A^2+I+\sqrt{2}A)=a+b\sqrt{2}$ and then $\det(A^2+I-\sqrt{2}A)=a-b\sqrt{2}$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Hence we obtain $a^2-2b^2=29$, which has no solution.